# IE8 Dot versus Bracket Notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a strange issue in IE8 where I'm trying to grab something by simply doing:

```
window.frames.frames[0].name; // get the name of the inner iFrame object
```

Nothing fancy, but when script is ran, IE7-8 interpret it like this:

```
window.frames.frames.0.name;

// which in-turn gives the error
// 'window.frames.frames.0.name' is null or not an object (which is not true)
```

**Why and how is it converting this, and why isn't it even working anymore??**

If I type the first one `window.frames.frames[0].name;` into the console of IE8, it grabs the correct iFrame. But typing in what IE8 interprets (`window.frames.frames.0.name;`), doesn't work at all... (strangely says, *"Expected ';'"*, which makes zero sense haha.

Anyone ever run into an issue like this?

Comment: Log the length of `window.frames.frames`, is it finding your node?

Comment: Why `windows.frames.frames` rather than `window.frames`?

Comment: The original window.frames would be the parent window itself (strangely enough) And @KevinB, it's coming back as 0... wow this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Hmm... so it has a 0 length. That doesn't mean it's undefined though i guess, if it's an object it won't have a length. Does it have the id or name that you expect it to? Basically, figure out where exactly in that chain it is breaking down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dot notation in the error message is just a string the browser uses, poor choice on the browser developers.

```
The line `window.frames.frames[0].name` does not make sense.
```

I would expect

```
window.frames[0].name
```

or if it is nested frame in a frame

```
window.frames[0].frames[0].name
```

Comment: Thanks epas, I know it makes absolutely no sense, frames[0].frames[0] also can't grab it... There is something inherently wrong with IE8 and iFrames, seems everyone has huge issues with them.

Comment: referencing it before it is loaded? Most people avoid frames/pop ups these days. :)

Answer (score 1):

`window.frames` is an array, is it not? Shouldn't you be indexing the first frame?

```
window.frames[0].frames[0].name;
```

Comment: `Window.frames` is only an array if there are multiple frames. In a single-frame page, `Window.frames` returns a valid object. In fact, `Window.frames[0]` fails.

Comment: Well it depends it is supposed to search by ID (in IE), and by name (in other browsers), but somehow array indexes are working... This gave pretty much the same result also :/

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you put parentheses around the the call? like this:

```
(window.frames.frames[0]).name; // get the name of the inner iFrame object
```

Also do you really mean do reference `window.frames.frames[0]` and not just `window.frames[0]`?

Or do you mean:

```
window.frames[0].frames[0].name; // get the name of the inner iFrame object
```